# How can I add to a dictionary if the values do not exist outside of an if statement?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dictionary

How can I add to a dictionary if the values do not exist outside of an if statement?

I have tried making the variable public:

```
Public dictAdd As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
```

I have tried making a function for it:

```
Public Sub dictEdit(serviceName As String, serviceValue As Integer)
    dictAdd.Add(serviceName, serviceValue)
End Sub
```

Add with:

```
'dictAdd.Add(serviceName, serviceValue)
 dictEdit(serviceName, serviceValue)
```

No matter what I do though, anything I add to the dictionary doesn't exist outside of the scope (like an if statement). I need to add and remove values throughout my entire code.

EDIT:

Here is my code:

```
Partial Class openapps_myapp
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Public dictAdd As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

Public Sub dictEdit(serviceName As String, serviceValue As Integer)
    dictAdd.Add(serviceName, serviceValue)
End Sub

'Add CBLAvailable item to CBLModifications
 Protected Sub BtnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAdd.Click

    'Some code here that gets serviceName and serviceValue from a checkboxlist

    'Add each selected item from CBLAvailable to dictAdd
    'dictAdd.Add(serviceName, serviceValue)
    dictEdit(serviceName, serviceValue)

End Sub

Protected Sub BtnEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnEdit.Click

    'Some code here that defines replaceString

If dictAdd.ContainsKey(replaceString) Then
                CBLModifications.Items.Remove(CBLModifications.Items(i))
               'right here is my error - dictAdd doesn't have any values - it's empty
            End If

End Sub

'More irrelevant code here
```

Comment: *anything I add doesn't exist outside of the scope*. What scope? Another class? Where did you declare that Dictionary? How are you trying to access it *outside the scope*. Try a public property instead. Referencing the owner of that object.

Comment: @Jimi It is all in the same class. I need to simply add values to the dictionary throughout the class. I can add them within an IF statement, for example, but outside of that IF statement, the values aren't in the dictionary.

Comment: It seems like you have declared the _dict_ variable inside a method of that class and not outside of any methods

Comment: Show where you have declare that Dictionary. Also, *anything I add doesn't exist  (...)*. Is it what you're trying to add that's unaccessible or the Dictionary itself. You have to give the necessary context.

Comment: @Jimi I've edited my question with some of my code. BtnAdd_Click successfully adds values to the dictionary called dictAdd. Meanwhile BtnEdit_Click sees no values in dictAdd.

Comment: `dictAdd` declaration is correct. As long as you call it from inside your class, if could (and should) be `Private`. `dictEdit` is fine, too - although you should add some code to avoid duplicate keys or else your app will crash when the user tries to add twice the same key. How did you verify that the dictionary really added the new values? I suggest you place breakpoints on `dictAdd.Add(serviceName, serviceValue)` and on `If dictAdd.ContainsKey(replaceString) Then` (especially the second one) and verify what the hell is going on behind those variables (especially `replaceString`).